# C++ memory visibility, passing data between threads

Tags: concurrency, c++11

I use code like this and it seems to work fine:

```
void addActions(const vector<zero_arity_function>& _actions)
{
    actionsMutex.lock();

    for (auto entry : _actions) {
        actionsToRun.push_back(entry);
    }

    actionsMutex.unlock();
}
```

And the corresponding code that the other threads runs:

```
void runActions()
{
    vector<zero_arity_function> _actions;

    actionsMutex.lock();
    swap(_actions, actionsToRun);
    actionsMutex.unlock();

    for (auto f : _actions) f();
}
```

But I'm trying to understand how memory visibility works to confirm this code is actually correct. I am not worried about the use of the mutex, i.e. having one thread add actions and having another thread access that vector at the same time. I am worried about memory visibility. For example, if the actions weren't copied by value, but were pointers to objects created in one thread and passed to another, how do I know the CPU knows to synchronize those blocks of memory from one thread to another. (i.e. the objects created in one thread might be in one thread's L1/L2 cache, and hasn't been copied to L3 cache or main memory and a thread running in a different core doesn't have access to that data yet).

As I understand it, use of mutex (and atomic variables) automatically creates a memory fence, but I don't understand if that handles this. I'm guessing this question has a definite answer since the C++11 memory model.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding how threads work - blocks of memory are not "synchronized" between threads in any way, memory is a shared resource and it's up to the programmer to ensure access is controlled appropriately.

Comment: Question updated: when a thread runs in one core, it uses L1/L2 cache which is local to that core. In order for that data to be accessed by another thread, it has to be synchronized to L3 cache or main memory.

Comment: This is a question on cache coherency. Modern CPUs organize the memory into "cache lines"; they track the current status of cache lines across cores and levels of caches. Examples of cache coherency protocols are MOESI and MESIF. You can search for these topics on Wikipedia. Cores must request permission from the coherence protocol before performing any memory operation. If a cache line currently resides in one cache and a different core wants to modify its data, it must first make a request to get exclusive write access.

Answer (score 6):

This is a question on cache coherency. Modern CPUs organize the memory into "cache lines"; they track the current status of cache lines across cores and levels of caches. Examples of cache coherency protocols are MOESI and MESIF. You can search for these topics on Wikipedia. Typical cache line granularity are 32, 64 or 128 bytes for most modern general purpose CPUs (excluding mainframes and embedded controllers).

To ensure correctness in accessing data structures in multi-threaded C++ code, one of these conditions must be met:

1. Fences and barriers are used correctly, to ensure that at most one thread is accessing the entire data structure at any time.
2. Proper safeguards (but not necessarily involving fences or barriers) are implemented, to ensure that all of the threads perform read-only operations on the entire data structure, and that no threads are allowed to perform modifications on any part of the data structure.
3. Locks, fences and barriers are used correctly, to ensure that modifications to the data structure from one thread do not begin, until all other threads stop reading the same data structure. Similarly, these synchronization mechanisms are used to ensure that all other threads do not start reading the same data structure until the modification is complete.

By "the entire data structure", this refers to everything that is accessible given the starting point. For example, if a C++ function is given a vector of value objects, the cache line containing the management block of the vector class is the starting point. From this, the dynamically allocated (resizable) array used to store the vector items can be accessed. Finally, the individual items stored on the vector array can be accessed. If the vector contains pointers as opposed to value objects, the pointed-to objects can also be accessed via those pointers. "The entire data structure" refers to all of the above.

The conditions that are outlined above will ensure that reads and writes to the entire data structure can proceed correctly (coherently). There are shortcuts possible, but it requires a long learning process and programming experience to avoid nasty multithreading bugs.

The C++ memory model is a theoretical construct on top of the hardware behaviors of CPU cache coherency architectures. These hardware behaviors are designed by their respective vendors, and are not necessarily identical (e.g. they are different on x86 family and ARM family). The C++ memory model provides basic guarantees about code correctness across these vendors, provided that all of the coding guidelines are being followed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I shouldn't have to worry about memory visibility or cache coherency as long as I use the right memory fence instruction. But does using a mutex as in the example code generate the right memory fence instruction? I think so, but you didn't say. Also, what if I used an atomic variable, e.g. setting an atomic bool to true while the vector is being accessed and setting it to false afterwards, making a spinlock in case it fails to set it to true because it's currently being accessed in the other thread? Which makes sense for short critical sections.

Comment: @stands2reason The exact semantics in C++ are a little convoluted, but documented in the C++ spec. Mutex provides a syncronized-before (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock) relationship between a call to lock and previous calls to unlock. This then establishes a transitive Inter-thread happens-before relationship between anything that is sequenced-before the unlock and anything the lock is sequenced-before. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) The compiler is responsible for ensuring appropriate instructions are generated to meet these guarantees.

Comment: @stands2reason As a programmer you shouldn't need to care about how the compilier decides which memory barriers it needs. Instead focus on what memory order guarantees the standard library is documented to provide.